# section head two environment with different size boxes

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec

I have two arguments in `section` and how to print the `second optional argument` in the same `boxes`. How do increase the `box` width should be upto `paperwidth`.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum,mdframed}

\definecolor{sectcolor}{cmyk}{0,1,.75,.39}
\definecolor{sectbgcolor}{RGB}{0,106,168}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\color{white}\bfseries}
  {\llap{\smash{\parbox[t]{2em}{\raggedleft%
      \colorbox{sectcolor}{%
        \makebox[\dimexpr2em-2\fboxsep\relax][r]{%
          \hfill\strut\thesection
        }%
      }\\[1ex]
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image1.png}\\[2pt]
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image2.png}\\[2pt]
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image3.png}\\[2pt]
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image4.png}\\
    }}\hspace*{0.5em}}%
  }
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{sectbgcolor}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}    {\strut#1}}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title Here}
\section{Number systems}{Consolidating}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Count systems}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have two questions: 1) Do you already have the redefinition of `\section` so as to have two mandatory arguments or is that one of the requirements in your question?. 2) Will every section have the two mandatory arguments or will this second title be optional (some sections will have it ans some others won't)?

Comment: 1) This is my requrements. 2) second `\section` title will be optional only (some \section will have one title only and some other \section will have two title).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of overloading the standard `\section` command (which can be done, but I don't consider a good idea), I propose you to use a new command `\Ssection` for sections with subtitle (for sections with no subtitle, you can still use the standard `\section` command):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum,mdframed}

\definecolor{sectcolor}{cmyk}{0,1,.75,.39}
\definecolor{sectbgcolor}{RGB}{0,106,168}
\definecolor{sectsubbgcolor}{RGB}{0,139,191}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\color{white}\bfseries}
  {\llap{\smash{\parbox[t]{2em}{\raggedleft%
      \colorbox{sectcolor}{%
        \makebox[\dimexpr2em-2\fboxsep\relax][r]{%
          \hfill\strut\thesection
        }%
      }\\[1ex]
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image-1}\\[2pt]
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image-2}\\[2pt]
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image-3}\\[2pt]
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image-4}\\
    }}\hspace*{0.5em}}%
  }
  {0em}
  {\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\colorbox{sectbgcolor}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\oddsidemargin-1in-2\fboxsep-5pt\relax}{%
    \strut#1%
    \if\sectionsubtitle\empty
    \else
      \hspace{5pt}\smash{\colorbox{sectsubbgcolor}{\strut\large\sectionsubtitle}}%
    \fi}
    }}%
  }

\makeatother

\def\sectionsubtitle{\empty}
\newcommand\Ssection[3][]{%
  \gdef\sectionsubtitle{#3}\section[#1]{#2}\gdef\sectionsubtitle{\empty}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Title Here}
\Ssection{Number systems}{Consolidating}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Count systems}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: How to move up the `\Ssection second` argument (like consolidating) without affecting the `framebox height`.

Comment: @Balaji In my example code, change `\colorbox{sectsubbgcolor}{\strut\large\sectionsubtitle}` to `\colorbox{sectsubbgcolor}{\strut\large\raisebox{3pt}[0pt][0pt]{\sectionsubtitle}}`. Instead of `3pt` use a suitable value.

Comment: Use `\markright{#2}` for printing the `section title` in the running head.

Comment: When using `\raisebox{3pt}` command line is not breaking in `\Ssection`. How to break the lines in `\section`?